# documentdb Error Invalid API version. Ensure a valid x-ms-version header value is passed

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I did a bunch of updates to some nuget packages last week on a .net core web application I'm working on and it broke my App. I've uninstalled and reinstalled vs2015 and gone through all the walkthroughs in microsofts docs. Finally today I did the .net core documentdb console app tutorial and got this error. I am using the documentdb emulator. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.1.0 library.  I got the same thing and then changing the project.json back to 1.0.0, the issue went away.  Maybe the emulator needs to be updated as well.

Comment: Had the same today, when started new project. By default nuGet manager installs latest SDK, but DocDB Emulator lacks updater, so it was not ready for 1.12.

Comment: Thanks!! That did it for me. I'd vote it up but I don't gots the rep yet :)

Comment: I received the same error with emulator version 1.11.72.11. After installing the latest version of the emulator from the website just now (1.11.136.2) I can upgrade the package to 1.1.0 and even to 1.2.1 (latest available).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-dotnet-core-getting-started) about developing a .NET Core console app using DocumentDB. In order to simulate your scenario, I installed the [Azure DocumentDB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator), then run `dotnet restore` followed by `dotnet run` to run the sample. The sample could work as expected on my side as follows:

[image]

[image]

In summary, please follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-dotnet-core-getting-started) and check the prerequisites before you run the sample. Also, please make sure the DocumentDB Emulator could launch successfully on your side.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I hadn't tried dotnet run from the pm console yet and that returned this error" DOTNET1017: Project file does not exist 'C:\Users\joelj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication
2\project.json'." which is strange because the dotnet restore said it successfully restored the project.json file. I know my system had the requirements to run this because it was working fine before I updated it, but i'll go through tonight and double check everything.